# Unresolved external symbol when including MFC object library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, linker, dependencies

I have an object file library that exists as a standalone `VC++` project. I have a number of other completely separate `VC++` solutions, and I would like some of them to utilise the classes included in this library.

I have added the project to a solution as detailed here: ([See docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx)). I have followed all of the instructions but am still getting `"unresolved external symbol"` errors when trying to use the class.

Can anyone help?

**Specifics:**
The class library in question is an SQL access library. Inside there are two files, sql.h and sql.cpp. Pretty simple. That project compiles itself absolutely fine, so I know there is nothing wrong with that project. I was under the impression that to get the project included in an existing solution I had to:

- Add the project to add the project to the solution
- Add a reference to the project
- Add the include directory
- Add `#include "sql.h"` to the project

That is what I have done, to no success.

Comment: An unresolved external symbol usually means that an external entity that you are trying to call is declared in a header file but not defined under that name in the library. As an example, you may be trying to use a library written in C in a C++ project. Or it may just be a typo in the header. Please provide specifics.

Comment: Sure; specifics added to original question.

Comment: Did you tell the linker that you are using an external library ?

Comment: Did you specify a correct path to your sql .lib file(s) ? Any typos there ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by either of those. I haven't specified any paths to .lib files - I've pointed the refernce to it in the "Framework and References" options. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the external library is linked into your project. It usually comes in a form of a .lib file (for example, sql.lib)
Go to Configuration Properties ->Linker and add your library to the "Additional Dependencies" list.